# Выборка и манипуляции с наибольшим числом в выборке

Tags: sql-server, sql

Есть запрос, который возвращает стоимость позиций в заказе (позиций может быть от 1 до over 9000).

Как выбрать наибольшие число из выборки и произвести с ним математические операции, а потом объединить с оставшимися числами?

**Обновление**

Допустим, запрос вернул нам 5 строк:
131
79
65
42
1

Мне нужно среди этих чисел выбрать наибольшее и вычесть из неё другое число. Но сделать это нужно только с наибольшем числом в запросе, а в результате вернуть модифицированное наибольшее и все остальные числа.

Comment: Ну, чтобы выбрать наибольшее число, воспользуйтесь функцией `MAX`.

> а потом объединить с оставшимися числами

Это как? Опишите проблему поподробнее.

Answer (score 1):

Попробовал для **sqlite3** набросать через `CASE`:

```
SELECT CASE

WHEN id=(SELECT max(id) FROM m) THEN id-1 ELSE id END

FROM m;
```

Таким образом, если значение выбранного идентификатора (id) максимальное в таблице, вернется значение данного идентификатора без единицы, иначе вернется значение идентификатора без изменений.

Подзапрос работает и без limit 1, может быть, в каком-то другом случае (СУБД) и придется использовать.

Простите, нет возможности проверить на transact-sql.